# Why does sh generate garbled output for set -x unexpectedly?

Tags: bash, sh

When I run shell script with `-x` option, I'll get more runtime debug information about the script, but sometimes this option will generate garbled output as bellowing,

```
$ sh -xc 'echo "中文"'
+ echo $'中?\226\207'
中文
```

But if I change a little bit this script, like adding a space at the beginning of the text,

```
$ sh -xc 'echo " 中文"'
+ echo ' 中文'
 中文
```

the output is absolutely right again! And you will find out that the `$` symbol disappears in the latter script. If I replace space to one of symbols `#{}[]()&~^*\;<>|`, I can also get similar right output. So what's happen to `sh -x`? Can anybody explain this to me ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd say there is some sort of bug in your shell's handling of Unicode characters in trace mode. `sh` is really some other shell running under the name `sh`; I can reproduce on my machine where `sh` is really `bash`, but running `bash` explicitly  (as well as `dash`, `zsh`, and `ksh`) produces the expected output.

Comment: Ah, are you on OS X by any chance? `sh` is `/bin/bash`, which is version 3.2 and displays the garbled output. Newer versions of `bash` work correctly.

Comment: THX@chepner, after upgrading bash to v4.3.42 through `brew`, this problem does disappear

Comment: Tested with bash 4.2.53, it displays $'\344\270\255\346\226\207'
With dash 0.5.8 it displays 中文, Ok too with zsh 5.0.2